# Glide does't put image into imageView

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I have next Adapter like this:

```
class ChatAdapter(chatItems: List<User>,
                  context: MainActivity) : RecyclerView.Adapter<ChatAdapter.ChatItemHolder>() {

    private val items= chatItems
    private val context = context

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ChatItemHolder {
        val itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.chat_item, parent, false)
        return ChatItemHolder(itemView)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = items.size

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ChatItemHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.firstName?.text = items[position].firstName
        holder.lastName?.text = items[position].lastName
        holder.initials?.text = setInitials(items[position].firstName, items[position].lastName )
        Log.d("__test__", items[position].avatarUri.toString())

     // Probleme is here
    Glide.with(context)
                .load(items[position].avatarUri.toString())
                .centerCrop()
                .into(holder.avatar)
        holder.isOnline?.visibility = if (items[position].online) View.VISIBLE else View.GONE
    }

    inner class ChatItemHolder(chatItem: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(chatItem){
        var firstName: TextView? = null
        var lastName: TextView? = null
        var initials: TextView? = null
        var avatar: ImageView
        var isOnline: View? = null
        init {
            firstName = chatItem.findViewById(R.id.tv_first_name)
            lastName =chatItem.findViewById(R.id.tv_last_name)
            initials = chatItem.findViewById(R.id.tv_initials)
            avatar = chatItem.findViewById(R.id.iv_avatar)
            isOnline = chatItem.findViewById(R.id.online)
        }
    }

    private fun setInitials(fn: String?, ln: String?): String {
        return if (ln.isNullOrEmpty())
            fn!!.first().toString() else fn!!.first().toString() + ln.first()
    }
}
```

but when I run my code, all work correctly exclude `Glide` but image does't appear. 
Why?
Others details of my `recyclerView` work correctly, `firstName`, `lastName`, `isOnline` fields appears all are needs detail of single view.

Comment: Can you please post your XML code?

Comment: There should be problem with Image URI. Have you check Log? and Image is from local or server?

Comment: If Glide is unable to load Image it logs error please see that for your source of error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer given by Sandesh is Absolutely correct and if u got any error setting an image to imageview using glide just add below line :

```
.error(R.drawable.your_image)
```

It will use image provided by you to set in an imageview if any error occured.
Thank you and help me improve my answer if anything is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Considering your `items[position].avatarUri` is of type Uri, don't call the `toString` method, maybe that's the problem

Comment: The data within items[position].avatarUri are next:

Comment: D/__test__: null
D/__test__: https://skill-branch.ru/resources/dev-intensive-2019/avatars/woman8.png

Answer (score 0):

Please add a listener in your glide code, that way you will get the reason(GlideException) why your image is not loading.

```
.listener(new RequestListener<Drawable>() {
                @Override
                public boolean onLoadFailed(@Nullable GlideException e, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                 //on load failed
                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onResourceReady(Drawable resource, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, DataSource dataSource, boolean isFirstResource) {
                    //on load success
                    return false;
                }
        })
```

Comment: Received null model